# Azure: Name resolution between VMs and role instances located in the same virtual network (Linux)

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, azure, virtual-network

I have deployed two ubuntu (14.04) machines with different cloud services in a virtual network (with default configuration). Now I would like to get the private ip of one of the machines from the other machine. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj156088.aspx#bkmk_IDNS) document this should be possible by using the FQDN.

When typing (from machine 1)

```
nslookup machine2.cloudapp.net
```

the public ip is returned. So either something is wrong or I'm using the wrong FQDN. If so, where can I find it?

Comment: The document. Where is it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the actual link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your VMs are not in the same cloud service**, they will not be mapped to their private address unless you add them manually to /etc/hosts file or setup your own dns server.

Example:

```
192.168.0.4  machine1
192.168.0.5  machine2
```

If you are refering to this line:

> Name resolution is provided between role instances and VMs located on
>   the same virtual network, but in different cloud services, by using
>   the FQDN of the target role instance or VM.

This will map to the public address only. It's **name resolution**, not **hostname**. It means that even if you block internet connectivity your VM will still know who *machine2.cloudapp.net* is but the resolution will be it's public ip address.